# Reason for difference stack smashing behaviour between machines

Tags: c, gcc, stack, stack-smash

We're trying to track down some stack smashing errors in some generated code. The problem is that the stack smashing errors are not 100% deterministic and only happens on one machine and not others. What possible reasons could there be for the difference in behaviour?

We're running gcc using the stack protector flags.

Comment: lots of reasons: installed amount of RAM, other apps running, cosmic rays....

Comment: Mitch: Is it really that bad? Are you saying we're completely at hands of chaos here?

Comment: Not Chaos but undeterministic sometimes; but if threads and timing are involved it could happen on rare or unpredictable occasions. I've seen multi-threaded code work 99 times out of 100....and then fail. If you are lucky it's just a stack overwrite error that happens all the time but only occasionally has consequences.

Comment: A stack is smashed by data, a buffer overflow is the most common cause.  There is very little reason to assume that *data* is repeatable.

Answer (score 2):

Try using [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)

[Memcheck: a memory error detector](http://valgrind.org/gallery/linux_mag.html)

If threads and timing are involved it is possible that it could happen on rare or unpredictable occasions. I've seen multi-threaded code work 99 times out of 100....and then fail. If you are lucky it's just a stack overwrite error that happens all the time but only occasionally has consequences.

[Ptrcheck: an experimental heap, stack and global array overrun detector](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/pc-manual.html)

[-fstack-protector + valgrind ==> stack array overflow debugging?](http://davegoodell.blogspot.com/2009/07/fstack-protector-valgrind-stack-array.html)

You could try enabling stack canaries with `gcc`'s `-fstack-protector-all` option.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! We're already using `gcc`'s stack protector, which is how we detected the problem. Using `valgrind` gives me nothing though. Any concrete suggestions for how to use it?